# SEOquake is not recogonizng microformats

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, seo-software

I generated Rich snippets (for organization) microcode for one of my websites, using instructions like

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146897?hl=en

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microformat

Problem I have is that Microformat is not recognized by tools like SEOquake.

Can you help me how to generate microdata in proper format?

Comment: Who cares if SEO quake recognizes it?

Comment: ie. my client :-)

Comment: You should politely advise your client that writing code purely to satisfy SEOQuake is stupid :-)  Because your code focus should be search engines and end user compatibility, not silly toolbars and other sites that check content and generally give outdated information.

Comment: Do you look for an implementation with Microformats or with Microdata? Your title says Microformats, your question says both, your tags say Microdata.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a correct microdata format, SEO quake doesn't report on any type of mark up, so there is no point in changing.

It is largely for reporting on off site parameters, the only onsite parameter it can report on is page titles.

You could always create a parameters for it that would report on mark up:

[Writing Parameters For Seoquake](http://www.seoquake.com/pages/articles/writing_parameters.php)